# Webbrowser.DocumentText is different from WebPage as displayed in the UI

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I load a web page in webbrowser on UI, then I submit a form and get a table.

The issue is that if I try to extract the Webbrowser.DocumentText I don't get the table in it.

But if I exit sub and then I try again to extract Webbrowser.DocumentText (without reloading the web page)  Webbrowser.DocumentText is correct.

How can I get correct Webbrowser.DocumentText  without exiting sub?

To be sure that web page is fully loaded I use this code before trying to extract Webbrowser.DocumentText:

```
Do Until Me.WebBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete : Application.DoEvents() : Loop
'Wait a little more
WaitALittle = Date.Now.AddMilliseconds(1500)
Do : Thread.Sleep(100) : Loop Until Date.Now > WaitALittle
```

Comment: It seems that you are not accessing the information displayed by the browser at the right moment (although quite difficult to tell for sure with your indications). Bear in mind that you have to wait for the document to be fully loaded; to make sure that this is the case you should rely on something like the `DocumentCompleted` event (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx). In the future, please ask properly by providing relevant code + indications.

Comment: @varocarbas Thanks, but the document is fully loaded. It may be a fault of webbrowser because I find something similar with solution on setting webbroser like IE9 but I wasn't able to do it

Comment: The only way to be completely sure that it is fully loaded is by relying on an event like the aforementioned one (the page might look like being fully loaded, when it actually isn't). Your the-second-time-works peculiarities seem to indicate that this is precisely the problem (= you are unadvertedly giving additional time to the page to fully load). The basic (proper) setup of the `WebBrowser` control includes a reliance on something like `DocumentCompleted` and triggering all the parsing actions from that event (= nothing should be done before it is triggered).

Comment: @varocarbas I edited my question

Comment: I will repeat it one last time: implement the `DocumentCompleted` event and call your parsing actions from it. The code you are showing is quite bad for various reasons. After a quick internet research, you should be able to find a sample showing how to write a properly-working code accounting for the `WebBrowser` control. Now you can wait for an answer (or apply the ideas I have proposed since my first comment and solve the problem by your own), but my help ends here.

Comment: @varocarbas Thanks, I thought that the code used was enough. Now I know that is not so. I'll try to do as you say.